# Distinguishing between realistic and wishful expectations

Tags: traducción

Since "hope" and "expect" both translate as *esperar,* how would you say something like "It was better than I expected, but not as good as I had hoped" in Spanish?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's true that both `hope` and `expect` can be translated as `esperar`, but they can have also other translations...

In most sentences you will only want to use one of the meanings, and it'll be quite clear which one you're meaning...

In this case, as you want to use both meanings, you'd better use synonyms, something like:

> Fue mejor de lo que **pensaba** / **suponía** / **preveía** / **figuraba** / **imaginaba**, pero no tan bien como  **deseaba** / **quería** / **me gustaría** / **me hubiera gustado**.

Note that `hope`, as you say, means a *wishful expectation*, so you can most of the times translate it by `desear` (=`wish`).

Answer (score 1):

I would nominalize either "expect" or "hope"; the former goes to *expectativa*, the latter to *esperanza* (context dependent). So:

> Rebasó mis expectativas, pero no mis esperanzas.

Or with some freedom:

> Rebasó mis expectativas, pero fue menos de lo que deseaba.

or

> Fue más de lo que esperaba, pero me decepcionó.

Comment: I think when you say `rebazó` you should use `rebasó` -with an **s**-, or is it that `rebazó` is used somewhere else?

Comment: Edited post to correct spelling.